# scrollTop is 0 for all parents even when scrolled

Tags: html, css, scroll

Here is a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZTt3S/) test.

This CSS causes no problem on a page where the content has overflow:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;    
}
body {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

But once this CSS is applied, despite scrolling, no element has a non-zero scrollTop:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;    
}
body {
    overflow: auto;
}
html {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The problem seems to be applying overflow: hidden to the html element* causes the scrollTop of the body element to always return 0. Which makes no sense. **There is a scrollbar with a non-zero position. How do I read/control it?**

* doing this to prevent some ugly artifacts from CSS transitions, but also because it makes sense; we only want the body to scroll. Removing it is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could create a fixed, fullsize wrapper around your page and remove the `overflow:auto` from the body. Then, the scroll you would be reading would not be from the body, but from the wrapper.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZTt3S/1/